# AmCharts split lines

Tags: javascript, amcharts

**I have Stacked bar chart with negative values**

[image]

if is possible split each line by another category? **Horizontally!**

[Code exemple](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values/)

tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can add another dimension to your data, and then create a graph object within the `graphs` array defining where and how it should display.

Using the `open` property, along with `valueField` allows you to create a new bar within the stacked collection with its own open/close values.
I am assuming this is what you mean by "splitting" the line horizontally.

In the dataProvider array, you can add these new open/close values to your individual objects, and use the field names to properly instruct the `graph` object on how to display them.

```
// individual dataProvider object
{
    "age": "0-4",
    "male": -5.0,
    "female": 4.8,
    "other_low": -2,
    "other_high": 2
}



// Accompanying graph object
{
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "openField": "other_low",
    "valueField": "other_high",
    "title": "Other",
    "labelText": "[[open]]% - [[value]]%",
    "labelPosition": "middle",
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return item.category + ": " + Math.abs(item.values.value) + "%";
}
```

[Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/Slothluvchunk/pen/yowMmB)